# What is the origin of the "...on the X" phrase?

Tags: expressions, phrase-origin

Example phrases:

- "...on the regular"
- "...on the daily"
- "...on the down low"
- "...on the DL"

I'm curious whether these have a common origin. (Maybe there are more examples I can't think of right now too.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On** (prep.)

> Used as a function word to indicate **manner of doing something**
> —often used with *the*
>
> *on the sly*
> *keep everything on the up-and-up* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)

> **11 a.** In (a certain way);
> Also forming adverbial phrases of **manner** — *on the cheap,* *on
> the sly* (OED)

Other examples that come to mind: *on the fly, on the double, on the rebound, on the q.t.* Of course each phrase has its own etymology, but I think this explains the function of *on*. The OED's citations for the "in a certain way" meaning go back to the origins of English.